# How to create a click event that will collect the values of multiple text boxes

Tags: c#

I have a windows form (C#) with several text boxes.  The user will input numeric values for a range of measurements in each one, of possibly 28 text boxes.  I would like to create a click event (cmdCalculate) that will simply collect all the values that have been entered, then send them in the form of an argument to a method for the purposes of various calculations in an effort to avoid all the calculations being done with the values directly from the form.

Having trouble with the syntax... when I place all the code for the calculations in the click event all is well, but I have been advised (by an experienced coder) that it is better to collect the values and calculate via a procedure/method...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code/attempt?

Comment: I had no code attempt - this concept is new to me; collecting text box values for calculation via a method - I am perfectly content with performing the average, sum, etc calculations via the click event, just though I would try to apply a higher level of code to the form

Comment: Or maybe your existing code?

Comment: Yes a custom method helps from duplicating in other areas where you want to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a method like this:

```
private List<string> CombineValuesFromTextBoxes()
{
    var values = new List<string>();
    var allTextBoxes = GetChildControls<TextBox>(this);
    foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxes)
    {
        values.Add(textBox.Text);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Or you may to use LINQ:

```
private List<string> CombineValuesFromTextBoxes()
{
    return GetChildControls<TextBox>(this).Select(childControl => childControl.Text).ToList();
}
```

To enumerate all textboxes without hardcoding use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls<TControl>(Control control) where TControl : Control
    {
        var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
        return children.SelectMany(GetChildControls<TControl>).Concat(children);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but I need a click event to initiate the collection - user clicks cmdCalculate, values collected for the text boxes, click enet calls method which performs variety of calculations based on which values entered - or is it better to have the calculations performed by the click event

Comment: Add button on form then double click on them it'll create eventHandler inside your form. After this call CombineValuesFromTextBoxes and do what you want.

Comment: works great thank you

Comment: Can you set my answer?)